# How to resume background service when Android 4.4 device has gone in standby mode?

Tags: android, service

It has been observed that when android 4.4 device is gone in **sleep/stand by** mode then application background service is forcibly stopped by Android System.

I tried below things:

1. Started service with START_STICKY
2. Made service as Foreground service
3. Used Work Manager

But nothing worked so far. Please suggest if any other options could be checked.

Answer (score 0):

In order to bring your app to the foreground, you must call `startActivity()` from another context (either a `Service` or a `BroadcastReceiver`). Just calling `startActivity()` from within an Activity won't bring your app to the foreground.

You don't need the `ACTION` and `CATEGORY` in your `Intent`, but you do need to set `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.

Comment: Thanks for getting some time to answer this post. Please read my question again as your answer doesn't seem relevant to my question

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using wake locks in your background service.

From the documentation :

> If you need to keep the CPU running in order to complete some work
>   before the device goes to sleep, you can use a PowerManager system
>   service feature called wake locks. Wake locks allow your application
>   to control the power state of the host device.
>
> **Note:** Using wakelocks causes battery drain, go through the
>   documentation and use alternatives such as WorkManager if this work
>   can be deferred.

References :

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html

Comment: Thanks for getting some time to answer this post. I tried wake locks as well but that too didn't work. 
Let me explain the exact behavior of my app. My one screen app is an OBU app for car headunits which has a background service to always need to run. So even if the app's process gets killed or device is rebooted, my app's background service should keep running which is working very well. But there is one case when headunit goes in sleep mode after 30 sec of idle state which is causing my app's background service getting forcibly stopped. It happens with any non-system background service.